# VSFTPD default permissions for new files vs new directories

Tags: vsftpd

I'm running `vsftpd` and have a specific question:

The `file_open_mode` and `local_umask` options let me configure, what permissions a newly created file/folder should have.

**The problem:**
I want 0660 for new files but 0770 for new folders (All files and folders should be readable and writable by owner and group - folders need the `executable` bit so that it's possible to open them)

How can I configure that?

(I searched this forum, google, vsftpd.man page, tutorials, manuals..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

The default `file_open_mode` of `0666` and `local_umask` of `0007` will give you file permissions of `0660` and directory permissions of `0770`.

### File permissions

As you already pointed out, files are created with the permissions set in `file_open_mode` (modified by the `local_umask`). Therefore, to get files created with `0660` you can keep the default `file_open_mode` and modify it with a `local_umask` of `0007` to get `0660` as the result.

### Directory permissions

Directories are created with mode `0777` modified by the `local_umask`. The only supporting documentation I found about this is in the source code itself. As there is no official browser-readable source code available, I can only link to an unofficial source code mirror at https://github.com/dagwieers/vsftpd/blob/3.0.2/postlogin.c#L1179 where the "tunable umask" in the comment refers to the `local_umask` configuration.

```
  /* NOTE! Actual permissions will be governed by the tunable umask */
  retval = str_mkdir(&p_sess->ftp_arg_str, 0777);
```

Comment: Great - works like a charm. I'm astonished, that this essential parameter is not described in the manuals.